# The Excel Fourier transform of Gaussian does not match the analytical FT.

Tags: normal-distribution, fast-fourier-transform

I am trying to match the excel FT (Fourier Transform) of a Gaussian to the analytical FT.

My Column A goes from 0 to 4095, column B goes from -2048 to 2047.

Column C is: C1=(1/200*sqrt(2 pi())) exp(-0.5*(B1/200)^2), which is a Gaussian.

Using Excel's Fourier Analysis pack, I FT column C and put the output in Column G.

Column H is: H1=IMABS(G1).

Column F is: F1=A1/4096.

Column J is the analytical FT of the Gaussian: J1=exp(-0.5*(F1*200)^2).

But, columns H and J do not match (using column F as the x-axis). Oddly enough, columns H and J match up great when I change column F to F1=A1/650. But why 650? It makes no sense. The same is true when I change the SD from 200 to 100.

Comment: This is not the site for questions about software.

Comment: I posted the question after I searched "Excel" in Mathematics and found many math related Excel questions asked and answered. Is there a more appropriate forum?

Answer (score 1):

Since your original interval has length 4096, the fundamental frequency (with one full wave fitting on that interval) is $f_1=2\pi/4096$. The frequencies for which the result is computed by a discrete Fourier transform are multiples of this $f_1$.

So you should have computed your analytical control result for those same frequencies, which means that column F should have been filled with $2\pi/4096$ times column A. Now $2\pi/4096$ happens to be $1/ 651.8986...$, so that is essentially what you already found.

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much. It's been bugging me for days!